# writing a text from a table using tsql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write an output text file from table. I am not getting any errors but the file is not created.

```
 EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.table1" queryout "C:\employee.txt" -T -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,'
```

No file is created, I am not sure why. Can anyone pls help?

I am not getting errors instead I get following messages:

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
 [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
 [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
[-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]



[-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]

[-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
[-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
[-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  NULL
```

I am running it on server A but the database is on server B. so on server A I used SQL SERVER management studio and gave the server B details to log on. After that I wrote query as mentioned above. so the file is going to be formed on which server?

Comment: That does actually work for me despite the apparent additional comma at the end and the fact you are specifying `T` and passing in a username and password. What version are you on?

Comment: I have removed the comma at the end also removed the user name and password. But still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query was correct -

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.table1" queryout "C:\employee.txt"
```

-Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,'

while typing in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT studio I pressed enter after queryout so statement "C:\employee.txt" -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,' was coming in next line.
because of this I was not getting any error or

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me even with or without the spaces after the username and pass.  Do you have write access to C:\ on the server box?  Do you need username or pass if you are also using -T?

Comment: I am running it on server A but the database is on server B. so on server A I used SQL SERVER management studio and gave the server B details to log on. After that I wrote query as mentioned above. so the file is going to be formed on which server?

Comment: on server the statement is executed, Server A

Comment: the query was correct -

    EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "SELECT * FROM DB.dbo.table1" queryout "C:\employee.txt" 
-Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,'

while typing in SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT studio I pressed enter after queryout so statement "C:\employee.txt" -Sservername -U user111 -P pwd -c -t,' was coming in next line.
because of this I was not getting any error or output file.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx):

> **Security Note**
>
> When the **bcp** utility is connecting to SQL Server with a trusted connection using integrated security, use the **-T** option (trusted connection) ***`instead of`*** the *user name* and *password* combination.